# How to use Click Button Keyword for Mat-Icons?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How to use Click Button keyword for Mat-Icons?
Selenium Library Click Button keyword locator contains the only name, id, value but when we inspected CSS element in the application we can't see the name, id, value, We can see an only class in the inspected CSS element.

```
<a _ngcontent-c5="" class="d-flex flex-grow-0 align-items-center p-3 download-button" mattooltip="Download this Robot" mattooltipposition="left" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-0" cdk-describedby-host=""><mat-icon _ngcontent-c5="" class="mx-1 clickable mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">archive</mat-icon></a>[css [XPath locator][1]locator][1]
```

Comment: Can you share HTML code ? What you have tried so far ?

Comment: `archive` is a button ??

Comment: the archive is Mat-Icon name

Comment: How to download a Zip folder or file using to Click Mat-Icon button in Robot Framework

Comment: The test case will be passed but the Zip folder is not downloaded

Comment: In the Selenium Library, Click Button doesn't have locator to use XPath right. Selenium Library Click Button locators are the only id, name, and value. Then how to use in this case?

Comment: There are several more locators , xpath, css selector, linkText, partialLinkText. Click method is for web element. locator is just a way to find web element on the web page.

Comment: Button with locator 'xpath://a[@mattooltip]/mat-icon[text()='archive']' not found and Button with locator 'css:a[mattooltip] mat-icon[class*='mat-icon']' not found i got this errors

Comment: Can you share URL ?

Comment: Which URL your asking?

Comment: The website you are automating.

Comment: You would mean application portal URL?. Sorry, we can't share with you that's privacy.

Comment: Thanks! for your approaches, It's worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this xpath :

```
//a[@mattooltip]/mat-icon[text()='archive']
```

css selector would be :

```
a[mattooltip] mat-icon[class*='mat-icon']
```

Just make sure these should be unique in DOM

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  *** Settings ***
  Library  SeleniumLibrary   implicit_wait=10

  ***keywords ***

 Click Element  xpath://a[@mattooltip]/mat-icon[text()='archive']
```

Comment: Thanks!, What credit I want to give you? Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.